# Continuous play on widgets

Tags: soundcloud

I'm building a web page with my songs, each song is in a single widget with a single track. I'm using the mini player (since I have a Pro plan) in a wordpress installation with the wp shortcode.

Is it possible to play the next song every time the previous one is over?

I noticed that when a song is playing and I press play on another, the first one stops, so i'm guessing there is a way - via Javascript or something - to know when a track is at the end and make the next start.

Comment: nothing already, i'm more a designer than a programmer and to be honest I don't really know where to start...

Answer (score 0):

You would have to bind events for each widget and code the "FINISH" event which is triggered when a track finishes playing.

Code snippet of binding FINISH event

```
  widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, 
  function finishedPlaying() { 
     YOUR CODE HERE....
    }
  );
```

You would also have to detect which widget had just finished and call play on the next widget. When a widget starts playing, it will automatically pause any other widgets playing.

If you have a group of tracks you want to play sequentially, would it not just be easier to create a "playlist" and put all the tracks into that and set the ***auto_play*** parameter to true?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! For design reasons I don't want to have a playlist on that page, but I'd rather have single tracks.

I'll try with your snippet, I'm not really good with javascript but It's a start, I hope I can figure out something :)